# jQuery on click event not working on a button but works well on other links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

So I've got a cart drawer on my e-commerce site that I want to get to open on click whenever the 'Add To Cart' button is clicked.

Comment: because it submits a form causing page to reload

Comment: no... script in one page can't do anything on a new page that gets loaded. The script on first page is gone. The form could be submitted using ajax though. Or open the cart every page load if it has anything in it

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, however, i think your button may not be firing because of duplicate `id` fields.`id`'s are considered unique to one element while `class`'s can be applied across many elements. Your javascript `('#AddToCart')` will only run on the first element with that specific `id`. Check your code just to be sure.

Comment: out of curiosity, what was your mistake?